# Close topic once Paypal purchase is made

Tags: php, paypal, phpbb3

I have an option on my phpBB forum to add a Paypal Buy Now button to enable users to sell and purchase items.  I would like to have the ability to automatically close a topic once a user makes a purchase through paypal to avoid multiple users from purchasing the same item.

Is it possible to get the user's session data from paypal once they make a transaction?  Then incorperate session data into a variable like:

```
$paypal = (isset($_POST['purchased'])) ? true : false;
```

Not sure if I need to download the Paypal SDK for this or not.

Any suggestions would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to get the user's session data from paypal once they
>   make a transaction?

You really want to trust the user's session data?  I am sure you can read the session data, you don't want to do that, would be trivial task to alter it.  Even if you can you really shouldn't read the session data for another website.

> Not sure if I need to download the Paypal SDK for this or not.

This would be the correct way to do it.

Comment: Figured as much.. been avoiding because of time restraints in learning a new program, never used it before.  If there is another method,  I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

When I last used it, Paypal Standard allowed you to specify a return URL (where to send the user) for failures and for successes. Dynamically generate some secret hashes to facilitate when the user is finally redirected.

Or you can use IPN.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.  As in hashes, do you mean with Pearl?  I am writing in PHP so I would probably mitigate arrays, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on the return URL. Buyers can (and will) close their browser / tab after completing a payment.
Instead, use PayPal Instant Payment Notifications to receive a server-to-server notification from PayPal which you can subsequently verify and use to update your database with the appropriate flag for a phpBB closed thread.

IPN works as follows:

1. You create the PayPal  and incude a "notify_url". The value for this parameter will be the full URL to a script on your server, called the 'IPN script' or 'IPN handler'.

You can specify an IPN handler as follows for Website Payments Standard
`<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://blah.com/ipn.php`

For Express Checkout or Website Payments Pro, simply include the following in your SetExpressCheckout/DoExpressCheckoutPayment or DoDirectPayment API call respectively.
    `NOTIFYURL=http://blah.com/ipn.php`

1. A buyer completes a transaction via PayPal
2. Once the buyer completes the transaction, he/she may close the browser, or return to your website
3. Once the transaction is accepted and processed by PayPal, PayPal will send out a notification to  http://blah.com/ipn.php
4. You need to take all POST data that was sent to this script, and POST it back to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate
5. If the data you send back matches the data PayPal sent you, a 'VERIFIED' response is returned.
6. If the response is VERIFIED, it's at this point that you would look up the matching transaction/buyer on your end, and update the phpBB thread status appropriately.

Some sample code and documentation for PayPal IPN is available at https://www.paypal.com/ipn/
In addition, some tips on making a secure IPN script are available at https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppmtsrobertg/securing-your-instant-payment-notification-ipn-script

Note: If you want to include any custom data along with the transaction which you can read out later, use 'custom'.
    `<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="xxxxx">`
This will also be returned in the IPN POST data sent from PayPal.